# Classic ASP invokes dll - works in 32 bit OS but fails in 64 bit OS with IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, regsvr32

I am working on a Classic ASP application. It used dlls to upload and download files to web server.

FunctionUpload.dll is registered using the regsvr32.exe command. It works fine in Windows 2003 server , 32 bit OS with  IIS 6.

Now the server is upgraded to Windows 2008 64 bit OS with IIS 7.5.  I registered the dll using regsvr32.exe  command in 64 bit OS. ( regsvr32.exe in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder using Admin login)

When the ASP code tried to create an object of that dll it fails.

```
Set download = Server.CreateObject("FunctionUpload.File")
```

Please let me know what steps need to be done to access the dll from ASP code on a server with windows 2008 64 bit OS with  IIS 7.5?

How to check if the dll is registered properly on a 64 bit OS?

Should I make any changes in the IIS 7.5 settings to invoke that dll?

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable 32-bit applications in your iis under your application pool

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. I enabled 32 bit applications in the application pool which is used.
When I invoke the dll, the ASP code fails and a message is shown in IE saying " Internet explorer cannot display the webpage "

Set download = Server.CreateObject("FunctionUpload.File")
ASP code fails and show IE cannot display the webpage after this line.
download.ToName filename

How to get the exact error message that occurs while calling the dll?

Comment: in your iis under classic asp Settings enable "send errrors to browser" in the debug section. furthermore you have to configure your IE to Show Long http error Messages. (Properties->Extended->remove the check at Show short error Messages)

Comment: You should look at your IIS logs.  On my computer they are located in the following directory: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles.  Choose the folder prefixed with W3SVC that was most recently updated.  Then open today's log.  You should see more details for the error.